# How to use rendered data using jinja in rendered template but without showing it in html page?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

```
{% for item in dlist %}
      <p>{{ item }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{% for i in range(dlist|length) %}
    {{ dlist.pop(0) }}
{% endfor %}
```

After using the list "dlist", I want to clear the data on it it so that upon next iteration the list starts from size 0. But if I do it this way upon using dlist.pop(0), the data is being printed on my html page and I don't want that. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show us the current output?

Comment: This whole thing is printing the list 2 times. I want pop function to just delete and not print

Comment: Still it is not clear. All we wondering is why you need the two for loop in the first place. Is just to print the serial number then there is some better solution then two for loops.

Comment: First loop is to show the data that I have in my list on my html template. With second loop I just want to remove the elements from list and my pop function is doing so but at the cost of printing it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to clear the list completely, you can clear the list using `clear()` method. Details of the method [can be read from the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

The `{{}}` delimiter will display the result even if it is `None` value. We need to block it as we want to clear the list only and we do not want to show `None` after executing it. I have added a condition inside the delimiter to hide the `None` from output.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def home():
    dlist = ["Ahmedur", "Rahman", "Shovon", "arsho"]
    return render_template("data.html", dlist=dlist)
```

`data.html`:

```
{% for item in dlist %}
    <p>{{ item }}</p>
{% endfor %}

{{ dlist.clear() if dlist.clear()}}

<hr>

{% for item in dlist %}
    <p>{{ item }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Output:

[image: clear list in jinja2 template]

The second for loop after the `hr` tag is not showing any value in the output. Because `dlist` doesn't contain any value after the execution of `clear()` method.

Comment: This is working perfectly and my template(its a error showing page for a file uploaded) is showing data once only but if I close this window and I open up error page again then it shows nothing as I have cleared the dlist. What I want is to remove the data only when I close my browser or home template file. Is there a way with which upon every new session my dlist initializes to 0 size? I have declared dlist as a global variable in my view file and I'm passing it to route by using a function.

Comment: @Ashwani, I am happy that the answer helped. Stackoverflow doesn't appreciate asking or answering question in comments or multiple questions in a single question. Please ask a separate question regarding the global variable/session management with updated code snippets.